# I had generate Public Key by Java spring security and I try to use that public key to encrypt data with Nodejs Crypto but it return error

Tags: java, node.js, express, rsa

I had generate public key using Java Spring Security, but I can not use that public key to encrypt the data using Nodejs crypto library. I think it is because of its format(X509).

My Nodejs code

```
module.exports.encryptRsa = (toEncrypt, pemPath) => {
  let absolutePath = path.resolve(pemPath);
  let publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
  let buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt);
  let encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
  return encrypted.toString("base64");
};
```

My Java code

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
                keyGen.initialize(2048);
                KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
                PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
                PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
                byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
                byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
                String formatPrivate = privateKey.getFormat(); // PKCS#8
                String formatPublic = publicKey.getFormat(); // X.509
                FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("publicKey.pem");
                fos.write("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
                fos.write(enc.encodeToString(publicKeyBytes));
                fos.write("\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
                fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's `getEncoded()` method returns the public key in format called 'spki' by Node crypto. Java's name for that format is "X.509", an unfortunate choice because it causes confusion with certificates of that name.

The proper PEM header for spki keys is simply `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`. Just get rid of `RSA` in the header and footer.